# Instance history on sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have a Sagemaker instance that was changed from large to medium by someone, is there any way to check history and reset it back to the previous instance type?

Comment: Did you check cloudtrail to see what was the event history related to sagemaker

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Amazon SageMaker is integrated with AWS CloudTrail, a service that provides a record of actions taken by a user, role, or an AWS service in SageMaker. CloudTrail captures all API calls for SageMaker.
More [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html).